AWS Lambda with Image package type doesn't update to "latest" on "sam deploy"
I have a lambda function specified in an AWS SAM template file with the "Image" package type, as follows:
  MyLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Role: foobar-lambda-role
      PackageType: Image
      ImageUri: !Sub ${AWS::AccountId}.dkr.ecr.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/foobar:latest

The docker image foobar:latest is pushed to ECR in my bitbucket CI before sam deploy, but the lambda function doesn't update to the newly pushed image after the deploy is completed.
If I manually call aws lambda update-function-code ... or go to the console and update the function's code, it works as expected.
Is there a way to make AWS SAM (or CFN) to update the lambda function automatically?

You need to invoke sam build before sam deploy.
